# Regular expression parsing issue

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I need to parse the below string, and want to use regular expression but can figure the correct way to do it.

Input Sample (token separator is `;` and inside the token is any Char i.e. M/W/D )

```
1W4;2W35;4M35;13W108
```

Expected output

```
List<string> points = new List<string>() {"1W", "2W", "4M", "13W"};
List<int> intervals = new List<int>() {4, 35, 35, 108};
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you don't need to use REGEX to split you can only use `String.Split` function 

try the line of code below :

List<string> points =  mystring.Split(';').ToList<string>();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just split your string on tokens by using [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) and then parse each token using regex:

```
var exp = new Regex(@"^(?<point>\d+[a-zA-Z])(?<interval>\d+)$");
var str = "1W4;2W35;4M35;13W108";
var tokens = str.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
    var match = exp.Match(token);
    if (match != null)
    {
        points.Add(match.Groups["point"].Value);
        intervals.Add(int.Parse(match.Groups["interval"].Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you pass the string "1W4;2W35;4M35;13W108;" notice the comma in the last char, you're getting cast exception. I added a check 
 if (match != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))

Comment: @UshaP, in this case is better to use `str.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` by using another [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) overload.

Answer (score 1):

a more restrictive regex could be:

```
var regEx = new Regex("^([0-9]+[MWD])([0-9]+)$");
```

With group 1 and 2 as youre output:

```
var regEx = new Regex("^([0-9]+[MWD])([0-9]+)$");
var str = "1W4;2W35;4M35;13W108";
var vals = str.Split(';');
foreach (var v in vals)
{
    var match = regEx.Match(v);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly liberal regex, in that it will tolerate differences in the input (e.g. it doesn't care about `;`):

```
var points = new List<string>();
var intervals = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+[MWD])(\d+)"))
{
    points.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
    intervals.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```